# how to write JavaScript object in the textarea(HTML Tag) to get that object by using documentQuerySelector

Tags: javascript, html, object

I wanna write javascript object in Textarea or input field and wanna retrieve those data by using documentQuerySelector. but when I do this it returns a string.

IS there any way to write javascript code in the browser and access that code form my javascript file like app.js

**HTML**

```
<textarea />
```

I use Event for the value In react

**JS / REACT**
I

```
e.target.value
```

the object that i write in the text area

```
{
  quizTitle: "React Quiz Component Demo",
  quizSynopsis: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim",
  questions: [
    {
      question: "How can you access the state of a component from inside of a member function?",
      questionType: "text",
      questionPic: "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=X", // if you need to display Picture in Question
      answerSelectionType: "single",
      answers: [
        "this.getState()",
        "this.prototype.stateValue",
        "this.state",
        "this.values"
      ],
     correctAnswe": "3",
      messageForCorrectAnswer: "Correct answer. Good job.",
      messageForIncorrectAnswer: "Incorrect answer. Please try again.",
      explanation: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
     point: "20"
    }
  ]
}
```

but when i retrieve the data and console.log it gives string instead of js object

```
"{
  quizTitle: "React Quiz Component Demo",
  quizSynopsis: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim",
  questions: [
    {
      question: "How can you access the state of a component from inside of a member function?",
      questionType: "text",
      questionPic: "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=X", // if you need to display Picture in Question
      answerSelectionType: "single",
      answers: [
        "this.getState()",
        "this.prototype.stateValue",
        "this.state",
        "this.values"
      ],
     correctAnswe": "3",
      messageForCorrectAnswer: "Correct answer. Good job.",
      messageForIncorrectAnswer: "Incorrect answer. Please try again.",
      explanation: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
     point: "20"
    }
  ]
}"
```

Comment: First of all check this line: correctAnswe": "3"

Comment: e.target.value is the value property of the DOM element, in this case that means the text entered in the textarea, so try to use JSON.parse(e.target.value) and don't forget to insert a correct JSON in the textarea.

Comment: I check this. What i want is to remove this  " " before the curly brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event.target.value` for textarea in this case will return you a string

If you want the object, you must use `JSON.parse(textValue)` to get it

Moreover, the `textValue` passed to `JSON.parse` must be a valid JSON (you could look at the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) for more detail on what a valid JSON would look like)

For example, to get it, you could declare an object and use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to get the valid JSON.

```js
const a = {
  quizTitle: "React Quiz Component Demo",
  quizSynopsis:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim",
  questions: [
    {
      question:
        "How can you access the state of a component from inside of a member function?",
      questionType: "text",
      questionPic: "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=X", // if you need to display Picture in Question
      answerSelectionType: "single",
      answers: [
        "this.getState()",
        "this.prototype.stateValue",
        "this.state",
        "this.values",
      ],
      correctAnswer: "3",
      messageForCorrectAnswer: "Correct answer. Good job.",
      messageForIncorrectAnswer: "Incorrect answer. Please try again.",
      explanation:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      point: "20",
    },
  ],
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2));
```

```
{
  "quizTitle": "React Quiz Component Demo",
  "quizSynopsis": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim",
  "questions": [
    {
      "question": "How can you access the state of a component from inside of a member function?",
      "questionType": "text",
      "questionPic": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=X",
      "answerSelectionType": "single",
      "answers": [
        "this.getState()",
        "this.prototype.stateValue",
        "this.state",
        "this.values"
      ],
      "correctAnswer": "3",
      "messageForCorrectAnswer": "Correct answer. Good job.",
      "messageForIncorrectAnswer": "Incorrect answer. Please try again.",
      "explanation": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "point": "20"
    }
  ]
}
```

After having a valid JSON string, paste it in the textarea, and when you get the value from textarea, just `JSON.parse()` that value to get your object value

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')

  const handleClick = () => {
    try {
      console.log(JSON.parse(value))
      alert('check the console log')
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err)
      alert('not a valid JSON')
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <textarea rows="30" cols="60" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
      <br/>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Get JSON</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit cranky-shape-7hggw]

Comment: @AsaduzzamanHimel did you copy the right JSON string (https://imgur.com/ajf6Mlp)?